# Equivalent condition for all entry of vector $x$ being nonnegative

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am wondering if there is an equivalent condition for "*all entries of vector $x$ are nonnegative*."

**The reason for this problem**. As we all know that if we want to show a matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite, we can either show that all eigenvalues of it are nonnegative or for all vector $x$, $x^TAx\ge0$. I found that the latter one is often used in proofs of some linear algebra theorems.

The situation now is similar, I found showing all entries of $x$ are nonnegative may not be easy in my situation. Thus, I want to know if there is any research or conclusion about it.

**Motivation for this question**. As suggested in the comments, this problem seems to be too large. I need to introduce the motivation to this problem. My real problem is:

> Given a matrix $A$ and a vector $z\ge0$, where $A$ is a symmetric matrix that satisfies $A_{ij} \le 0$ for $i\neq j$, and $A_{ii} = 1 + \sum_{j\neq i} |A_{ij}|$. We can sort the value of $z$'s entry so that $z_{k_1}\ge z_{k_2} \ge \cdots \ge z_{m} \ge \cdots \ge z_{k_n}$. Then a new vector $x$ can be generated as follow:
> $$
> x_j = \left\{
> \begin{array}{lc}
> mean(z_{k1}, z_{k_2}, ..., z_{m})  & j \in {k_1, ..., m}\\
> z_{j} & z \notin {k_1, ..., m}
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
> What I want to verify (or falsify) is that given $Az\ge 0$, then can we have $Ax\ge 0$?

Thanks ahead!.

Comment: What's a situation in which you would not be able to check that directly?

Comment: Vectors don't have much internal structure (like matrices) so I doubt there is any useful and non-obvious way of checking this.

Comment: @RiversMcForge Given that $Az\ge0$, I need to prove $Ax\ge0$, where $x$ is correlated with $z$. Checking each entry would focus on each row of $A$. I thought if we can prove it in a compact way (not checking each entry) would be a better idea.

Comment: What is the specific nature of the “correlation” between the vectors $x$ and $z$?

Comment: It may be a little complicated. Sort the value of $z$ in descending order: $z_{k_1}\ge z_{k_2}\ge \cdots \ge z_{m} \ge \cdots \ge z_{k_n}$, and calculate the mean of the largest $m$ values as $[z]_m$. Then, the value of $x$ is just replacing $z_{k_1},...,z_{m}$ as $[z]_m$.

Comment: @yuejiang_li That’s something you would want to put in the statement of your question. Otherwise, this question is too open-ended, and sounds more trivial than it is.

Comment: If $z$ has nonnegative entries, and the entries of $x$ are averages of entries of $z$, $x$ would automatically have nonnegative entries, no?

Comment: @RiversMcForge Thanks for the advice, I will re-edit this question and give full information. If $z$ has nonnegative entries, then $x$ surely have nonnegative entry. However, what I want to have is $Ax\ge 0$ rather than $x\ge0$. I will add more information about $A$ and $z$.